# Hide IntelliJ Idea Problems view

Tags: view, intellij-idea

Is there any way to hide the Problems view tab?

I chose it in Tools Window, but can't find any way to hide it again. Even editing the project XML doesn't help.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just click the down arrow, on top right of problems window, or click shift+escape while focussed. You can also remove the tool bar - `view > and un tick.`

Comment: This minimizes the tab, but not hides it.

Comment: you want to completely remove any message regarding compilation ? I have heard better ideas.

Comment: Thanks, I found it view > tool name indeed (Idea takes some time to get accustomed...).